# flutter web issue: keyboard is not opening when pressed on textfield

Tags: flutter, flutter-textformfield

When I add some text in Textfield then keyboard is not opening, closing automatically.

I have assigned UniqueKey to textfield's Key parameter.
I have added Form key as well.

My keyboard will open whenever I press on textfield

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As for web keyboard will not open because by default it takes input cable keyboard as always open.

Comment: what is the solution for this?

Comment: For flutter for native there is not really any solution as far as I know. But you can do a workaround. check this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/virtual_keyboard_multi_language)